# How to test the relationship between variance of functional trait value (dependent variable) and elevation range of occurrence?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, linear

I have a data set consisting of functional trait values for trees across an elevation gradient. Hence each functional trait value (dependent variable) has a corresponding elevation value (independent variable). How do I test if the variability in functional trait values corresponds to the elevation range?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Question - Does the variation in functional trait value correspond to range of occurence. I need a test for this questions specifically, or a test where I can at least infer this.

Comment: How many traits? Are they yes/no for each tree? A mixed species forest might have more conifers per acre at higher altitude but a probability of a tree disease, or tree height might vary within each tree species and altitude. So, if you show what your data looks like, maybe someone figure out exactly what information can be extracted from it.

Comment: Hi I have collected data on intra -speciifc trait variation. There are a total of three traits and 5 species for which I have collected functional trait data for individuals of the 5 species across a 1600 m elevation gradient.

Comment: You might then need to refine your question: (1) is it about variance across species, within species, across all individuals at a particular elevation (which would depend on the relative abundance of different species)? (2) are you interested in treating the traits as independent or modelling their covariance? The answer I provided below addresses only the simplest possibility of these.

Answer (score 1):

This can be answered in a regression framework: regress variance in traits against elevation. If the relationship is nonlinear, you might want to try a GAM instead of a simple linear regression.

I suggest you do some reading on the topic before proceeding, though. It's impossible for us to foresee all the complications you may encounter in this analysis and a good grasp of the basics will help you.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I have only 5 species and therefore only 5 datapoints for which I have values of total within species variance (I'm taking coefficient of variance as a measure) associated with an elevation range. Due to this low sample size, I don't think I will be able to regress variance of a trait with elevation range. Anything else that I can do?

Comment: @AshishNambiar Could you elaborate on your data in the question? 5 species, how many elevations, how many individuals per elevation per species? And again, what precisely is your question?